# Access DOM element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, dom

I want to access the DOM and get an element by id: i want to get image.src from my html file that looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Diagram</title> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script> 
//    <!-- I use many resources -->
    <script></script> 

    <script> 

      function generatePNG (oViewer) { 
        var oImageOptions = { 
          includeDecoratorLayers: false, 
          replaceImageURL: true 
        }; 

        var sResultd = new Date(); 
        var h = d.getHours(); 
        var m = d.getMinutes(); 
        var s = d.getSeconds(); 

        var sFileName = "diagram" + h.toString() + m.toString() + s.toString() + ".png"; 

        var sResultBlob = oViewer.generateImageBlob(function(sBlob) { 
          b = 64; 
          var reader = new window.FileReader(); 
          reader.readAsDataURL(sBlob); 
          reader.onloadend = function() { 
            base64data = reader.result; 
            var image = document.createElement('img'); 
            image.setAttribute("id", "GraphImage"); 
            image.src = base64data; 
            document.body.appendChild(image);
          }  
        }, "image/png", oImageOptions); 
        return sResult; 
      } 
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body > 
    <div id="diagramContainer"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Besides of nodejs, phantomjs, what other javascript-server  i can use to get an element by id from html file?

Comment: You can use cheerio https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio it's server side jQuery

Comment: @jcubic i'm trying with cheerio but it doesn't work because in my html file the image.src is in the script tag

Comment: A little confused about what you're asking here. It looks like you're dynamically generating an image in base64 and appending it to the body... What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I understand that you're trying to access the DOM element you've created, but how are you trying to access it? With what language? Why can't you just use `$('#GraphImage')` and access it via JavaScript? More detail?

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee i have tried to to get $('#GraphImage') but i get undefined

Comment: Once you run your `generatePNG()` function is the DOM element being successfully created? Can you do an `Inspect Element` on it and show what the output in the DOM actually looks like?

Another thing to remember is if you're trying to access it before it's been created, you'll never find it. Are you attempting to access it via an Event listener? If so, are you using the `.on()` property as so: `$( document ).on( 'click', '#GraphImage', function() { ... });` ??

Comment: @lionelRitchietheManatee i think that the element dom is not created when i try to get it with cheerio, what can i do?

Comment: can you add the code that calls `generatePNG()` and the code that tries to access `$('#GraphImage')` to your question so we can get a more complete view of things?